# MySQL query with distinct pairs of values

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the following table

```
  ID1 ID2
1   a   b
2   b   a
3   c   d
```

I am trying to write a query where rows like 1 and 2 are returns because they are essentially the same just reversed by column, so I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Likes A, Likes B
WHERE  A.ID2 = B.ID1 AND B.ID2 = A.ID1
```

This returns

```
  ID1 ID2
1   a   b
2   b   a
```

The next step  for me is to return only the first one i.e. return only distinct rows where where `A.ID2 = B.ID1 AND B.ID2 = A.ID1`.

Comment: you need a row number....

Comment: i wouldn't say that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a range comparison in the join criteria to limit it to just one row.

```
select l1.*
  from likes l1
    inner join likes l2
      on l1.id1 = l2.id2 
        and l1.id2 = l2.id1 
        and l1.id1 < l2.id1
```

This will select the row with the alphabetically lowest id1.  Unless you need some other criteria for choosing which row to return?